# To find, wether '1' lies in the range of f, where $f(x)=[ln(\frac{7x-x^2}{12})]^\frac{3}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

$f(x)=[ln(\frac{7x-x^2}{12})]^\frac{3}{2}$,

For the given function, the question is whether, f(x) can equal 1 for some real value of x?

Comment: can you find when $\frac{7x-x^2}{12}=\mathrm{e}$?

Comment: no. I can see that the max. value for the fraction is about 1.02... But there is a textbook which says that f(x) = 1 is possible.

Comment: @OP see the fine answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The tactic is to make things simpler.

If there is $x$ such that $f(x)=[ln(\frac{7x-x^2}{12})]^\frac{3}{2}=1$ then we have also

$ln(\frac{7x-x^2}{12})=1$, that is, $\dfrac{7x-x^2}{12}=e$ or even simpler

$x^2-7x+12e=0$

You just have to check wether this equation has real solutions.

Comment: no. it does not has real value...

Comment: @Raja So you have your answer...